# show imageview in android toolbar at top left corner before title

Tags: android

I want to show imageview on android toolbar before the Title but its not working , it gives me image after title on the right side , can anyone help I want image to be at left at the beginning of toolbar
    [image]

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Abstract.AbstractActivity">



        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#0F6177"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageViewplaces"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_question_mark"
                />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>




</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here's the activity

```
package com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Abstract;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Activity.ChartStyle;
import com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Activity.SelectLanguage;
import com.astro.famouspandit.R;

public class AbstractActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_abstract);



        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;


    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int items = item.getItemId();
        switch(items){

            case R.id.action_Language:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,SelectLanguage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }break;

            case R.id.action_CharStyle:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,ChartStyle.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could trying using the [`setIcon()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) method. Remove the `ImageView` from your `Toolbar` in your layout file, and add the following to your `Activity`

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_question_mark);
```

**Edit:** You may also need to include `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`

Comment: I think it still needs `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`

Comment: @PPartisan its working but how can i put spaces between imageview and title

Comment: @M.Sameer its working but how can i put spaces between imageview and title

Comment: @bipin IMO, if you want to customise the design of your `Toolbar` any further then I would recommend you create a completely custom layout for it (i.e. Rohit's answer)

Comment: @bipin actually you do not need to customize the toolbar for that. If you use a `TextView` for the title, just remove it and call `setTitle()` of the Toolbar or ActionBar. Even setTitle of the Activity itself will work.

Comment: @M.Sameer can you elaborate??  i am not using any textview its taking the class name as title by default

Comment: @bipin if you are not using any textviews then what you see as a default title is the Activity title .. IMO you should call setTitle(""); in the onCreate of the Activity, then call toolbar.setTitle("The new title"); .. the space between the icon and the title is standard and you should leave it as it is .. If you believe what you see is not correct please attach a screenshot for us to see.

Answer (score 6):

Just set the layout_gravity="left" for ImageView and layout_gravity="center" for TextView. Hope This helps:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
>
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a textView Before ImageView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#0F6177"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

   <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/title"
               android:text="title"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageViewplaces"
                android:torightof="@id/title"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_question_mark"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: i am going to use this for all my activities so this way i'll have to use android:text="title" for every activity and thats lenghty  by using this method

Comment: but you need to customize your tool bar so you need to do this